# Rails 4: Redirect not working after a POST request made

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So we have two models, Articles and Likes. An article `has_many :likes`, a like `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :article`. The resources are nested as below:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :likes
end
```

We have logic in our view that renders a "like" or "unlike" button as follows:

```
<% unless signed_in? and current_user.likes? @article %>
  <%= link_to "Like this article!", article_likes_path(@article), method: :post, remote: true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Unlike this article!", article_like_path(@article, current_user.article_like(@article)), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Here is our LikesController:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article
  before_action :set_like, only: [:destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  after_action :redirect_to_article, only: [:create, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def create
    like = Like.new
    current_user.likes << like
    @article.likes << like
    redirect_to @article
  end

  def destroy
    @like.destroy
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

    def set_like
      @like = Like.find(params[:id])
    end

    def like_params
      params[:like]
    end

    def redirect_to_article
      redirect_to @article
    end
end
```

In the view, the likes count is rendered with:

`<%= @article.likes.size %>`

**The problem is**, after we hit "like" or "unlike", the like (or unlike) goes through the backend, but we have to manually refresh the page to see the like count refresh. In other words, the two calls to `redirect_to @article` in the LikesController do not actually refresh the page.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your buttons are using `remote: true` which is telling Rails to use AJAX, but your controller is set to only respond to HTML. From you question, it sounds like you're cool with the page being refreshed, so just delete `remote: true` from the buttons and it should work.